# Inch ruler in Canvas/Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image]

How can I create above inch Ruler in Canvas. I tried many example but could not get success. Also found one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042440/fabric-js-ruler-with-zoom/41044804) in stackoverflow too,  but it's in CM not in INCHES and work differently.

Is there anyone who has worked on similar task or can suggest through the example to implement it, even any resource link will work for me.

Thank You!

Comment: Inches work the same as cm they just have a different scale. There is 1 inch in every 2.54cm. To turn cm into inches divide by 2.54. If you are converting from pixels to inches and only know the size of a pixel in cm just multiply the value by 2.54. The linked answer has all you need an as the scale is arbitrary and you only use inches you can convert to inches by just calling the units "Inches"

Comment: Thanks for comment. However it's little late i have converted the scale into inches. Can you help me calculate the width of an image in pixel based on DPI. Example: I have 700X400 image and I want to repeat it in a 470X405 canvas with 150 DPI then how can I calculate the with of image in pixel  to repeat?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you are wanting? A pixel is a Dot in DPI thus if you have a canvas 470 pixel across and you are printing at 150 DPI the image will be (470 / 150) inches wide.